# What is a 割り込みタスク?

Tags: usage, computing, metaphor

One of my coworkers todays said something like:

> "Today I have too many 割り込みタスク  so I cannot pay too much attention to
>   this project"

Literally translating it into "interrupting tasks" sounds rather vague,
so how would a 割り込みタスク be defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how common it is in general business Japanese, but `割り込みタスク` isn't that out of place among [lifehackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hack). It roughly means "unexpected work created by external factors".

Here are a few articles that use the word...

- [「バッファ時間」で割り込みタスクをやっつける](http://bizmakoto.jp/bizid/articles/0904/10/news039.html)
- [タスクシュート方式における割り込みタスク](http://www.mindhacks.jp/2010/03/post-2184)
- [割り込みタスクに四苦”ハック”](http://cyblog.jp/modules/weblogs/4106)

In lifehacking jargon, "interruptions" seems to be the corresponding term, though not exactly interchangeable (to be exact, interruptions = 割り込み, tasks created by interruptions = 割り込みタスク):

- [Plan for Interruptions to Minimize Their Impact](http://lifehacker.com/5496953/plan-for-interruptions-to-minimize-their-impact)

The point is, when you say 割り込みタスクが多い, the tasks themselves are interruptions to your coworker's planned work schedule, and that interruption has already happened. I think that's a more natural interpretation/transcription than "割り込**む**タスクが多い" (tasks keep interrupting me).

Answer (score 3):

I think you misheard `割り込みタスク`. `割り込みタスク` or `interrupting task` is a technical term used in computer science: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). Although it is a technical term, its meaning does not differ much from what you can imagine if it were an ordinary phrase. I think your coworker has some knowledge about computers, and used it metaphorically. Other than as a technical term, the phrase `割り込みタスク` would be too odd to be used.

Answer (score 1):

That's sound like

> "I have got too many urgent tasks for today, so I cannot pay attention to this project"